# Determining symbol names of the DLL

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I have worked with "CPPLoadLibrary" example (from Microsoft All-in-One framework)
Okay, there are two ways of export symbols from the sample DLL.

1. Export symbols from a DLL using .DEF files
   A module-definition (.DEF) file is a text file containing one or more module 
   statements that describe various attributes of a DLL. Create a .DEF file and 
   use the .def file when building the DLL. Using this approach, we can export 
   functions from the DLL by ordinal rather than by name.
2. Export symbols from a DLL using __declspec(dllexport) 
   __declspec(dllexport) adds the export directive to the object file so we do 
   not need to use a .def file. This convenience is most apparent when trying to
   export decorated C++ function names.

And so we have the following code.

```
typedef int     (_cdecl* LPFNGETSTRINGLENGTH1)      (PCWSTR);
typedef int     (CALLBACK* LPFNGETSTRINGLENGTH2)    (PCWSTR);

LPFNGETSTRINGLENGTH1 lpfnGetStringLength1 = (LPFNGETSTRINGLENGTH1) 
    GetProcAddress(hModule, "GetStringLength1");

LPFNGETSTRINGLENGTH2 lpfnGetStringLength2 = (LPFNGETSTRINGLENGTH2) 
    GetProcAddress(hModule, "_GetStringLength2@4");
```

So my question is how to determine the name of symbol in order to call GetProcAddress?
in first case it's pretty straightforward, we take that symbol name from .DEF file.
But what about "_GetStringLength2@4" 
What is underscore? What is "@4" stand for?
Thanks.

Comment: It is the standard decoration for the __stdcall calling convention.  The CALLBACK macro in the function pointer declaration also specifies __stdcall.  Using LoadLibrary + GetProcAddress is certainly something you want to avoid in general, it is far too error-prone.  Just let the linker take care of it, link the import library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't use a .DEF file, the export names are decorated according to their calling convention in order to support exporting overloaded functions.  See [Why can't I GetProcAddress a function I dllexport'ed?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040112-00/?p=41083):

> [T]he decoration scheme varies from architecture to architecture and from calling convention to calling convention. So, for example, if the function is exported from a PPC DLL, you would have to do `GetProcAddress(hinst, "..SomeFunction")`, but if it is exported from an 80386 DLL as `extern "C" __stdcall`, you would need `GetProcAddress(hinst, "_SomeFunction@8")`, but if it's `__fastcall` you would need `GetProcAddress(hinst, "@SomeFunction@8")`.
>
> What's more, C++ decoration varies from compiler vendor to compiler vendor. A C++ exported function might require `GetProcAddress(hinst, "?SomeFunction@@YGXHH@Z")` if compiled with the Microsoft C++ compiler, but some other decorated string if compiled with the Borland C++ compiler.
>
> So if you intend people to be able to `GetProcAddress` for functions and you intend your code to be portable to multiple platforms, or if you intend them to be able to use your DLL from a language other than C/C++ or use a C++ compiler different from Microsoft Visual Studio, then you must export the function by its undecorated name.

See [The history of calling conventions, part3](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040108-00/?p=41163) for a description of the various name decoration schemes.  In this case, the function uses the `__stdcall` calling convention, so it's decorated by prepending an underscore and appending a `@` sign and the number of bytes worth of parameters it takes.  It takes one word-sized argument for a total of 4 bytes, so it's decorated as `_GetStringLength2@4`.

Answer (score -1):

To answer your actual question, use your compiler's TDUMP or similar tool, or any other tool that can display an executable's exports table, so you can see the actual exported names.